# Debugging memory leakage: No backtrace saved in core dump after segmentation fault

Tags: linux, memory, debugging, gdb

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.186), and I want to debug a memory leakage in a program.

With `pmap -x PID`, I found the process's heap is increasing consistently.
To figure out where is the increment from, I added following codes to kernel mm/mmap.c,

```
--- a/kernel/kernel-5.10/mm/mmap.c
+++ b/kernel/kernel-5.10/mm/mmap.c
@@ -269,6 +269,12 @@ SYSCALL_DEFINE1(brk, unsigned long, brk)
                goto out;
        mm->brk = brk;

+       if (strstr(current->comm, "testprog")) {
+               printk("XXXXXX mm->start_brk: %lx, mm->brk: %lx\n", mm->start_brk, mm->brk);
+               if (mm->brk - mm->start_brk >= 0xd0000) {
+                       send_sig(SIGSEGV, current, 0);
+               }
+       }
```

So, when the heap size is more than 0xd0000, I would send SIGSEGV to the `testprog` to get its core dump, then with `gdb` to analyze the backtrace to figure out where is the increment from.

It succeeded in generating core, but with `gdb testprog core`, I only got partial backtrace,

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x77de1994 in brk () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x77de1a88 in sbrk () from /lib/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

It did NOT show where/who called `sbrk()/brk()`.

Then I tried to run the `testprog` with gdb, hope to capture the backtrace on-site, but I still failed to do that.

Here is the demo code of testprog.c for testing (the core did NOT show the full back trace).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
        p = malloc(0x2410);
        if(p == NULL)
        {
                printf("malloc error!");
                return 0;
        }

        printf("XXXXXXXXXXXX p = %p\n", p);
        printf("Press any key to deploy\n");
        getchar();

        memset(p, 0, 4100);

        printf("Will set more\n");
        memset(p, 1, 8192);

        while(1) {
                p = malloc(1000);
                printf("ppppp %p\n", p);
                usleep(1000);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to debug this kind of memory leakage (with core and gdb, both failed), and valgrind did NOT capture the real leakage.

Is there a way to help me in this? I have kernel source code, so I can modify it to assist debugging.

Comment: Does that help? [Coredump GDB "Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098822/coredump-gdb-backtrace-stopped-frame-did-not-save-the-pc)

Comment: Yep, this is really helpful! I cannot re-compile the GLIBC (which is provided by SDK vendor), but I found the libc.so.6 is stripped when it is installed to target system. By using the original libc.so.6 in the toolchain (without being stripped) I can get more contexts in backtrace, much better than before.  You can post your comment as the right answer. Thanks,